# PHP require_once() and 'use' not working within class

Tags: php

```
function ClassFBLogin($d){  
    require_once('Facebook/autoload.php');
    require_once('Facebook/FacebookSession.php');
    require_once('Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php');
    require_once('Facebook/FacebookRequest.php');
    require_once('Facebook/FacebookResponse.php');
    require_once('Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php');
    require_once('Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php');
    require_once('Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php');
    require_once('Facebook/GraphObject.php');
    require_once('Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php');
    require_once('Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php');
    require_once('Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php');
    require_once('Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php');
    require_once('Facebook/GraphUser.php');
    require_once('Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php');

    require_once('Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookGuzzleHttpClient.php'); 
    require_once('Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookStream.php'); 
    require_once('Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookStreamHttpClient.php');

    use Facebook\FacebookSession;
    use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
    use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
    use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
    use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
    use Facebook\GraphObject;
    use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
    use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
    use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
    use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
    use Facebook\GraphUser;
    use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;

    $this->a = $data;
}
```

when i run this program without class it works very fine but when i put all these codes inside a class i get following error:

**syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)**

is there any other way of calling "use" for a class? please help.

Comment: Try having the require and use statements outside your class and have the class below your require and use statements.

Comment: [Scoping rules for importing](http://php.net/manual/it/language.namespaces.importing.php#language.namespaces.importing.scope)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[PHP: Using namespaces: Aliasing/Importing - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#language.namespaces.importing.scope):**

> #### Scoping rules for importing
>
> > The *use* keyword must be declared in the outermost scope of a file (the global scope) or inside namespace declarations. This is because the importing is done at compile time and not runtime, so it cannot be block scoped.